# Spring Security and enterprise LDAP Authentication error

Tags: spring-security, ldap, spring-ldap

I am using Spring Security(basic authentication) + LDAP authentication which works well with embedded test ldif but not with my domain LDAP. **However**, I can use a LDAP browser/edit tool to search my account using the same filter(SamAccountName=napo)

```
@Override  
public void addServiceAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationManagerBuilder   authBuilder) throws Exception {
       authBuilder
            .ldapAuthentication()
            .ldapAuthoritiesPopulator(ldapAppAuthoritiesPopulator())
            .userSearchBase("OU=Users,DC=napo,DC=com")
            .userSearchFilter("(SamAccountName={0})")
            .contextSource()
            .root("dc=napo,dc=com")
            .managerDn("admin@napo.com")
            .managerPassword("XXX")
            .url("ldap://ldap.napo.com/OU=Users,dc=napo,dc=com");
```

The error message is: LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-0310020A, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT)

Answer (score 0):

The `userSearchBase` is relative to `root`. Remove `DC=napo,DC=com` from `userSearchBase`.